# What did Sputnik-1 sound like? Did it use multiple tones?

Tags: artificial-satellite, radio-communication, telemetry, sputnik

Radio transmissions from Sputnik-1 could be heard on short wave radios around the world.

**Questions:**

1. A carrier signal only would not be particularly audible to an AM radio listener, was it modulated with an audible tone, or was a [beet frequency oscillator (BFO) required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sideband_modulation#Demodulation) to make the signals audible and get a good fix on the Doppler shift versus time?
2. Was it a steady beep-beep-beep or was there a sequence of different tones? I ask because <s>the first video suggests only a repeating tone</s> (video no longer available) but the second video sounds like it's a sequence of four different tones, as if some telemetry were involved.

Comment: Russian version of Sputnik-1 wikipedia article gives three links to the sound of Sputnik, recorded in: 1)[Chechoslovakia](http://www.mentallandscape.com/Sputnik1_Czech.mp3); 2) [Washington](https://web.archive.org/web/20180929142334/http://mentallandscape.com/Sputnik1_WashingtonDC.mp3); 3) [Germany](https://web.archive.org/web/20180929142620/http://mentallandscape.com/Sputnik1_GermanHam.mp3). All three sound quite steady on the tone. I couldn't find any information on change of the tone (by design) in the original technical report on design of the transmitter.

Comment: The electronics of Sputnik-1 was build using vacuum tubes only. To save batterie power for heating the cathodes of the tubes only very few tubes could be used. The simplest solution was an unmodulated carrier without different tones, Keying the transmitter saved power in the period between two beeps.

Comment: The Amateur Radio stack has a lot of info on transmitting & receiving keyed Continuous Wave (CW) signals, eg https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/135 & https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/12823

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to just be a carrier signal alternately transmitted and not transmitted.  As the carrier is in the MHz range, the audio cannot be a direct mapping of that frequency.  I don't know the specific mechanisms used to make the signal audible as a particular tone, or whether that tone would differ between different receivers.

There are multiple recordings of it on http://www.dd1us.de/spacesounds%201.html.  While a few have varying pitch, they don't appear to repeat (and not over 4 beeps).  To my ear any variation in pitch sounds more like the variances you hear when trying to tune in a signal.  Most of the recordings have only a repeating tone.  I suspect that your second video is just a repeated loop of four particular tones.

One of the audio files contains some contemporary analysis by someone at Caltech.

> For the first three days, both signals were beeping -- that is the carrier was alternately switched on and off.  And it appeared that when one channel was on the other was off.
>
> [...]
>
> It is our personal opinion that these signals contain no telemetering, or at most a low accuracy telemetering of simple information, and that the beeping was for purposes of easy identification.

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_1#Design), the duration of the "on" signal could be modified by temperature and pressure information.  I couldn't find any sources that countered the assertion that the carriers were fixed and not (intentionally) modulated within the craft other than the sub-second transmitting/not transmitting periods.

Another [contemporary paper](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V02-N01/02-01-Guier.pdf) (Guier and Weiffenbach , "Theoretical Analysis of Doppler Radio Signals from Earth Satellites," Nature 181 , pp. 1525-1526 (1958). ) describes the signal capture this way:

> We had one distinct advantage over other groups: one of us was
> completing a Ph.D. dissertation in microwave spectroscopy and had a
> high quality communication receiver and the necessary understanding of
> how to make precision frequency measurements. Because of the fortunate
> happenstance that the Beltsville, Md. WWV 20-MHz standard broadcast was
> at nearly the Sputnik frequency, **the output from the receiver could be
> made to be the audible difference between the WWV standard and the
> Sputnik signal.**
>
> [...]
>
> Our first reception of the Sputnik seemed only a momentary triumph
> when we realized that there was no telemetry on the 20 MHz signal,
> just a pure tone that at first appeared to wander in frequency by a
> surprisingly large amount. After about 5 minutes, it was unmistakably
> clear that the wandering was the moving Sputnik's Doppler shift, which
> we were by then recording with precise frequency and time information.

That said, if the reported frequencies were accurate, the difference would be .005MHz or 5kHz.  While very audible, 5kHz is a pretty high tone.  None of the recordings I listened to seemed to have tones that high.  So I suspect a different method was used in general

Comment: The most relevant authorative data one could possibly find is contained in [this D-200 manufacturer report](http://russianspacesystems.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Otchet-o-razrabotke-bortovoy-radiostancii-pervogo-sputnika.pdf), but it's in Russian. It contains all reasoning of design choices made, electrical scheme, list of electrical parts used, etc. I couldn't find in it though the choice of tone and it seems there's no mentioning of the tone variance by design. The length of beep-pause-beep fractions were meant to be varying depending on pressure and temperature in the spacecraft.

Comment: The nominal audio frequency would normally be determined by the receiver, which synthesizes the audio, usually by mixing a synthesized (and tunable) "beat frequency" with an intermediate frequency generated from the received signal.  I say "nominal" because variations in signal frequency cause changes in the audio frequency, which is what makes e.g. Doppler shift audible to the operator.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to this question is that. No, it did not transmit audio beeps to radios. Sputnik 1 had a transmitter that would alternately turn off and on by a circuit called “the Manipulator”. It is a circuit that uses two relays to turn off and on both 20MHz and 40MHz, its speed was regulated by three modes or three inputs based on the satellite internally or externally. For example if the satellite was at 50 C the command was sent to the relay oscillator system and made the off and on go faster. If it was externally for example there was a leak or a puncture to the satellites skin, the command or signal was sent and alters the speed of the beeps

Here is the source and link to the answer above me. It is 46 Pages and has the schematic of the transmitter, close up pictures and answers to the on and off beeping signal, and several answers more to any questions if related to the Sputnik 1 transmitter. The document or paper listed in the link even goes into details about the power consumption of the manipulator circuit and the two transmitters, including a full reconstruction of the transmitters and the relay oscillator, this paper is also very recent as of this year, from May 23, 2023 [1]

[1]: Sputniks History
https://worldphaco.com/uploads/THE%20SPUTNIKSTORY.pdf ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20231231220424/https://worldphaco.com/uploads/THE%20SPUTNIKSTORY.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for your answer and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* But even your link discusses Sputnik's "beeps" at length (search the document, there are 18 instances of "beep") and starting on page 4 it explains why we call the pulses beeps.

Comment: Thank you! I do appreciate the feedback  and yes the pulses or beeps were because of the relays. Is that what you were trying to say?

Comment: no something less: that while "it did not transmit audio beeps to radios" is true, the people listening to those radios at home did indeed hear beeps, and these intermittent but otherwise unmodulated carrier pulses are also colloquially referred to as "beeps" because they sounded like beeps to radio listeners, either because a [BFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_frequency_oscillator) was used (on some radios) or because the 20.005 MHz carrier had an "opportunistic BFO" with the 20.000 MHz WWV AM radio carrier 5 kHz away. I guess I'm just commenting that "beep" is OK to use in this context

Comment: for example [Did Sputnik 1 tell us more than "beep"? What science was improved by information gained from its orbiting the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46333/12102) Anyway, thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Ohhhhh thats what you were talking about! Yeah no it is totally fine! I didn’t address that before the link so it was forgotten. I thought it would have been more helpful to just visit the link and read the lines, thank you! I’ll make an edit to my statement just to make sure! I am also very glad you found my answer to be helpful!